# 8-channel logic level shifter: how to get 3.3 V output voltage?

Tags: voltage, level-shifting

When I apply 4.8 V (Arduino 5 V) to the B side of my level shifter [TXB0108](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/txb0108.pdf), I always get 1.2 V (which is the minimum) on the A side.

Is it possible to get something like 3.3 V or at least 1.8 V (it's the minimal required for my device)?
[image]
Back side
[image]

Comment: Are you supplying 3.3V on the VA pin?

Comment: Are you trying to use a TXB0108 as a DC/DC converter? It isn't, it's a bidirectional logic level shifter *without direction control input*.

Comment: i use 5V, @greybeard what do you mean? It's supposed to reduce the voltage right? Power via VB to VA, and signal for the reset?

Comment: A logic level shifter is *not* supposed to reduce supply voltage. The datasheet you hyperlinked shows separate supplies \$V_{CCA} \  \le V_{CCB}\ \$ supplied externally and describes shifting levels *between port terminals*.

Comment: (Doesn't an Arduino supply 3.3 V in addition to 5 V?)

Comment: The chip may be fake: [examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbcRC.png). Just be aware of the possibility.

Comment: why photo? a circuit would be better to analyze your problem

Comment: i updated the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feeding 5 V into VB, it is *not* possible to get 3.3 V from VA:
Both VA and VB are power supply *inputs*.

There is no supply output:
This is a bidirectional *logic* level shifter without direction control input.

Converting one level voltage to another is a job for a (voltage) *converter*,
5 V DC to 3 V DC would be *DC/DC converter*, efficiency of 0.85 should be well possible.

*Voltage regulators* have been used for this; a "linear" one would have an efficiency below 0.6 here.

---

The use of a *logic level shifter* is to connect logic level terminals of sub-circuits with incompatible logic levels.
The supplier of the TXB0108 once published a [Voltage Level Translation Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/ml/scyb018h/scyb018h.pdf).

Comment: Ok thanks, so not for my need. When then i will need those level shifter? And in the meantime I discover SPX3819 for voltage regulator.

Comment: SPX3819 looks good enough. Keep in mind that you need to get rid of the power dissipated - in a 70°C environment going from 5 V to 3.3 V, that limits current to about 99 mA even with the DFN package.